# appengine - java - javascript: how to delete an entity with string as key from web front end

Tags: java, javascript, google-app-engine, endpoint

I have following problem: when I go to https://*.appspot.com/_ah/api#p/questionendpoint/v1/questionendpoint.removeQuestion and enter my string id which looks for example like "ahFzfnRyaXZpYWwtcGVyc3VpdHIQCxIIUXVlc3Rpb24Y4toBDA2" everything works fine.

If I call following code from my page, the deletion fails. Why? What am I doing wrong?
I call the `removeQuestion`Function with the same key as above... But it does not work... `req` looks correct and contains the correct rpcParams, the string key. And data holds the value `false`. I don't see what I do wrong...

```
var req = gapi.client.questionendpoint.removeQuestion(key);
req.execute(function( data )
{ 
    addInfo(data);
});
```

The endpoint function looks like following and is working (through the `_ah/api/...` Link)

```
@ApiMethod(name = "removeQuestion")
public Question removeQuestion(@Named("id")
String id)
{
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    Question question = null;
    try
    {
        question = mgr.find(Question.class, id);
        mgr.remove(question);
    }
    finally
    {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return question;
}
```

and the key of my question class is defined as following:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.encoded-pk", value="true")
private String key;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, NOW, I figured out how that works...

All functions from the engine seem to be using arrays...
So only following works (where `key` is my string value...)

```
var data = {};
data['id'] = key; 
var req = gapi.client.questionendpoint.removeQuestion(data);
req.execute(function( data )
{ 
    updateQuestionsTable();
});
```